# Alert Dialog Validation in Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, validation, kotlin, android-alertdialog

So currently I have an Alert Dialog text box in an Android Kotlin App. There are two parameters, edit text and a radio group with radio buttons in it. Currently I am trying to validate whether those fields have been filled out or selected. My first thought was to have a onClickListener for the confirm button but I don't know how to with my current setup.

```
confirmTag.setPositiveButton("Confirm")
                { dialoginterface, i ->

                    markerTitle = editText.text.toString()
                    val group = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.filterGroup)
                    //val groupId = group.checkedRadioButtonId
                    val addMarker = markerToData(it, markerTitle)
                    val check = it
                    Log.d("DAD", "Coord are:  " + check)
                    database.child("Markers").child(markerTitle).setValue(addMarker)
                    map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(it).title(markerTitle))
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Input f EditText is " + markerTitle,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                }
```

Comment: When you say “validate”, do you mean writing a test to assert correct functionality?

Comment: When I say validate I mean to check to make sure the edit text field has text in it and that a radio button is selected.

Comment: For usability reasons, instead of validating the input after the user presses the button, you should set it initially to be disabled. When the edit text or radio buttons are modified, they should call a validation function that sets the button's enabled state according to the current value of the radio buttons and edit text.

Comment: How would you do that? Can you provide an example?